# command-driven visual state in Xamarin.Forms custom control

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, icommand, visualstatemanager

I'd like to create a command-driven custom control in Xamarin.Forms. It should act like a normal button, with different states for normal an disabled. Everything works very well, but I can't get the bound command to drive the control's visual state with the CanExecute property of the command. I tried to use ButtonCommandPropertyChanged, but that's not fired when I call ChangeCanExecute() in my viewmodel.

Of course I could introduce another property on the control to change the state, but I think it should be possible to do this with the commands CanExecute status (and should be more elegant as well...)

[IconButton.xaml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView WidthRequest="180" HeightRequest="90"
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="TestStyle.Controls.IconButton">

<ContentView.Content>
    <Frame x:Name="MyFrame" Style="{StaticResource StandardFrameStyle}" Margin="5" Padding="10,12,10,10">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid RowSpacing="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image x:Name="InnerImage"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   Aspect="AspectFit"
                   Margin="0,0,0,1"
                   HeightRequest="35"/>
            <Label x:Name="InnerLabel"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}"
                   FontSize="12"
                   LineHeight="0.9"
                   MaxLines="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ContentView.Content>
```

[IconButton.xaml.cs]

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TestStyle.Controls
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class IconButton : ContentView
{
    public EventHandler Clicked;

    public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(IconButton), default(string));

    public string ButtonText
    {
        get => ((string)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty))?.ToUpper();
        set => SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonIconProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ButtonIcon", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(IconButton), default(ImageSource));

    public ImageSource ButtonIcon
    {
        get => (ImageSource)GetValue(ButtonIconProperty);
        set => SetValue(ButtonIconProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(IconButton), null, BindingMode.Default, null, ButtonCommandPropertyChanged, ButtonCommandPropertyChanged);

    private static void ButtonCommandPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"oldValue: ${oldvalue}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"newValue: ${newvalue}");
    }

    public ICommand ButtonCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(ButtonCommandProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(ButtonCommandProperty, value);
            Debug.WriteLine("ButtonCommand wurde gesetzt!!");
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(IconButton), null);

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }

    public IconButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(() =>
            {
                Clicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                if (ButtonCommand == null) return;
                if (ButtonCommand.CanExecute(CommandParameter))
                    ButtonCommand.Execute(CommandParameter);
            })
        });
    }
}
}
```

[FirstPage.xaml]

(I delete some irrelevant parts)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TestStyle.Controls;assembly=TestStyle"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:TestStyle.ViewModels;assembly=TestStyle"
             x:DataType="viewModels:ExampleViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TestStyle.Views.FirstPage"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LightBgColor}"
             Title="Test"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:ExampleViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <controls:IconButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                             ButtonText="Enable"
                             ButtonIcon="shuffle_gr.png"
                             ButtonCommand="{Binding EnableCommand}" />

        <controls:IconButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                             ButtonText="Disable"
                             ButtonIcon="clock_gr.png"
                             ButtonCommand="{Binding DisableCommand}" />

        <controls:IconButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                             ButtonText="Personal anfordern"
                             ButtonIcon="select_gr.png"
                             ButtonCommand="{Binding MyDynamicCommand}" />


        <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding StatusMessage}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

[ExampleViewModel.cs]

(I delete some irrelevant parts)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using TestStyle.Models;
using TestStyle.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestStyle.ViewModels
{
    public class ExampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _statusMessage;
        private bool _buttonState;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public string StatusMessage
        {
            get => _statusMessage;
            set
            {
                if (_statusMessage == value) return;
                _statusMessage = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StatusMessage"));
            }
        }

        public bool ButtonState
        {
            get
            {
                return _buttonState;
            }
            set
            {
                _buttonState = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ButtonState));
            }
        }

        public ICommand MyDynamicCommand { get; }
        public ICommand EnableCommand { get; }
        public ICommand DisableCommand { get; }

        public ExampleViewModel()
        {
            SetButtonState(true);
            MyDynamicCommand = new Command(() => StatusMessage = $"This is dynamic at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}", () => ButtonState);
            EnableCommand = new Command(() => SetButtonState(true));
            DisableCommand = new Command(() => SetButtonState(false));
        }


        private void SetButtonState(bool newState)
        {
            ButtonState = newState;
            var myCmd = ((Command) MyDynamicCommand);
            if (myCmd != null)
            {
                myCmd.ChangeCanExecute(); // I think my control should be notified here!?
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to wire up the change of the CanExecute to my custom control's visual state.

Any help highly apprreciated! :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I finally got it... This mechanism works the following way:

The custom control uses an extended constructor for the command's BindableProperty (notice the BindingPropertyChangedDelegate):

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonCommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("ButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(IconButton), null, BindingMode.Default, null, ButtonCommandPropertyChanged);
```

On initialization of the control the method ButtonCommandPropertyChanged gets invoked, which registers an EventHandler on the ButtonCommand for CanExecute-changes:

```
private static void ButtonCommandPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
{
    // wird bei Initialisierung des Buttons aufgerufen
    if (!(newvalue is Command)) return;
    var buttonCommand = (ICommand) newvalue;
    var iconButton = (IconButton) bindable;
    iconButton.ChangeEnabledState(buttonCommand.CanExecute(iconButton.ButtonCommandParameter));
    buttonCommand.CanExecuteChanged += (sender, args) =>
        IconButton_CanExecuteChanged(sender, new BindableObjectEventArgs(bindable));
}

private static void IconButton_CanExecuteChanged(object sender, BindableObjectEventArgs e)
{
    // CanExecuteChanged wurde ausgelöst, CanExecute muss erneut ausgewertet werden
    var iconButton = (IconButton) e.BindableObject;
    var executable = ((ICommand) sender).CanExecute(iconButton.ButtonCommandParameter);
    iconButton.ChangeEnabledState(executable);
}

private void ChangeEnabledState(bool state) => VisualStateManager.GoToState(MyFrame, state ? "Normal" : "Disabled");
```

In my ViewModel I need to inform my command, when the CanExecute has to be reevaluated:

```
private void SetButtonState(bool newState)

{
    ButtonState = newState;
    var myCmd = ((Command) MyDynamicCommand);
    myCmd?.ChangeCanExecute(); // Command von der Änderung seines CanExecute-Status benachrichtigen (löst CanExecuteChanged-Event aus)
}
```

That's it. VisualState of the custom control is now controlled by the command's CanExecute status.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer, which will help more people :)

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

You set the Command **MyDynamicCommand** as readonly , so it will never been changed .

**Solution:**

From your description , I guess that you want to change the border color of the third frame when tapping the other frames , right ?

It is not a good design to re-set the command in runtime . Since you had defined the `CommandParameter` . You would better binding the value of `ButtonState` to it .

#### in xaml

```
<viewModels:IconButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                             ButtonText="Personal anfordern"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding ButtonState}"
                             ButtonCommand="{Binding MyDynamicCommand}" />
```

#### in viewmodel

```
private void SetButtonState(bool newState)
{
  ButtonState = newState;         
}
```

#### in IconButton.xaml.cs

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(IconButton), null,propertyChanged:(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue) => {


                var iconbutton = bindable as IconButton;

                iconbutton.MyFrame.IsEnabled = (bool)newvalue ;


            });
```

Comment: Hi, yes I want to change the state of the third button by altering ButtonState with the other buttons. This could be anything else, like a validation, it's just an example at the moment. Binding the ButtonState directly to the control is the way I don't want it. I want the control to react to the CanExecute state of the Command.

Comment: Set `CanExecute` will not invoke the PropertyChanged Event .

Comment: I call `myCmd.ChangeCanExecute();` when changing the ButtonState property to invoke that event. At least that was my intention...

Comment: In that way you need to implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged on `MyDynamicCommand` and re-init it . Then invoke  myCmd.ChangeCanExecute();When the ButtonState is false .